# Another quesion about J.H. Conway's Surreal Numbers

Tags: set-theory

Let CF be Conway's real closed field of Surreal Numbers and let ACF be the algebraic closure of CF. Is there an Extension E of ZFC that provides for the existence of "proper classes", in which ACF can be defined (as the "class" of all "sets" satisfying a certain formula of E)?

Comment: Why won't it just be expressible as ordered pairs, much like $\Bbb C$ can be expressed as ordered pairs of real numbers?

Comment: It  is true that CF can be defined as a proper class in a set theory such as NBG, because CF contains all the ordinal numbers. But is the collection of all ordered pairs of elements belonging to a proper class also always a proper class in NBG? I suppose this is what I am not quite sure about. In other words, do proper classes -as well as sets - satisfy the axiom scheme of replacement in NBG?

Comment: It is definable, so it is a class. It is not a set, since in that case the projection map would mean the original class was also a set (by replacement).

Comment: Thanks. This really answers my whole question in the affirmative.  So, if one wanted to erect and study even a division algebra over the field CF, if seems that one could do it in NBG.